# PySpark Window function on entire data frame

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

Consider a PySpark data frame. I would like to summarize the entire data frame, per column, and append the result for every row.

```
+-----+----------+-----------+
|index|      col1| col2      |
+-----+----------+-----------+
|  0.0|0.58734024|0.085703015|
|  1.0|0.67304325| 0.17850411|
```

Expected result

```
+-----+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|index|      col1| col2      |  col1_min | col1_mean |col2_min   | col2_mean
+-----+----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  0.0|0.58734024|0.085703015|  -5       | 2.3       |  -2       | 1.4 |
|  1.0|0.67304325| 0.17850411|  -5       | 2.3       |  -2       | 1.4 |
```

To my knowledge, I'll need Window function with the whole data frame as Window, to keep the result for each row (instead of, for example, do the stats separately then join back to replicate for each row)

My questions are:

1. How to write Window without any partition nor order by?

   I know there is the standard Window with Partition and Order, but not the one taking everything as 1 single partition

   ```py
   w = Window.partitionBy("col1", "col2").orderBy(desc("col1"))
   df = df.withColumn("col1_mean", mean("col1").over(w)))
   ```

   How would I write a Window with everything as one partition?
2. Any way to write dynamically for all columns?

   Let's say I have 500 columns, it does not look great to write repeatedly.

   ```py
   df = (df
       .withColumn("col1_mean", mean("col1").over(w)))
       .withColumn("col1_min", min("col2").over(w))
       .withColumn("col2_mean", mean().over(w))
       .....
   )
   ```

   Let's assume I want multiple stats for each column, so each `colx` will spawn `colx_min, colx_max, colx_mean`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using window you can achieve the same with a custom aggregation in combination with cross join:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast
from itertools import chain

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  [1, 2.3, 1],
  [2, 5.3, 2],
  [3, 2.1, 4],
  [4, 1.5, 5]
], ["index", "col1", "col2"])

agg_cols = [(
             F.min(c).alias("min_" + c), 
             F.max(c).alias("max_" + c), 
             F.mean(c).alias("mean_" + c)) 

  for c in df.columns if c.startswith('col')]

stats_df = df.agg(*list(chain(*agg_cols)))

# there is no performance impact from crossJoin since we have only one row on the right table which we broadcast (most likely Spark will broadcast it anyway)
df.crossJoin(broadcast(stats_df)).show() 

# +-----+----+----+--------+--------+---------+--------+--------+---------+
# |index|col1|col2|min_col1|max_col1|mean_col1|min_col2|max_col2|mean_col2|
# +-----+----+----+--------+--------+---------+--------+--------+---------+
# |    1| 2.3|   1|     1.5|     5.3|      2.8|       1|       5|      3.0|
# |    2| 5.3|   2|     1.5|     5.3|      2.8|       1|       5|      3.0|
# |    3| 2.1|   4|     1.5|     5.3|      2.8|       1|       5|      3.0|
# |    4| 1.5|   5|     1.5|     5.3|      2.8|       1|       5|      3.0|
# +-----+----+----+--------+--------+---------+--------+--------+---------+
```

*Note1:* Using broadcast we will avoid shuffling since the broadcasted df will be send to all the executors.

*Note2:* with `chain(*agg_cols)` we flatten the list of tuples which we created in the previous step.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the execution plan for the above program:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(3) BroadcastNestedLoopJoin BuildRight, Cross
:- *(3) Scan ExistingRDD[index#196L,col1#197,col2#198L]
+- BroadcastExchange IdentityBroadcastMode, [id=#274]
   +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[finalmerge_min(merge min#233) AS min(col1#197)#202, finalmerge_max(merge max#235) AS max(col1#197)#204, finalmerge_avg(merge sum#238, count#239L) AS avg(col1#197)#206, finalmerge_min(merge min#241L) AS min(col2#198L)#208L, finalmerge_max(merge max#243L) AS max(col2#198L)#210L, finalmerge_avg(merge sum#246, count#247L) AS avg(col2#198L)#212])
      +- Exchange SinglePartition, [id=#270]
         +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_min(col1#197) AS min#233, partial_max(col1#197) AS max#235, partial_avg(col1#197) AS (sum#238, count#239L), partial_min(col2#198L) AS min#241L, partial_max(col2#198L) AS max#243L, partial_avg(col2#198L) AS (sum#246, count#247L)])
            +- *(1) Project [col1#197, col2#198L]
               +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[index#196L,col1#197,col2#198L]
```

Here we see a `BroadcastExchange` of a `SinglePartition` which is broadcasting one single row since `stats_df` can fit into a  `SinglePartition`. Therefore the data being shuffled here is only one row (the minimum possible).

Comment: I remember reading cross join is expensive. Window function is created for that : to bring the agg value to each row.

Comment: It is not in this case @Kenny. The crossJoin here will take place between df and stats_df with the last one having only one row. In this case the program will treat stats_df as an broadcasted value. The row will be broacasted on every executor and the join will just append the stats_df row to the rows of df

Comment: @Kenny I modified the answer by adding the execution plan of the query that shows that there will be not shuffling since the will be only a BroadcastExchange. If you need more information about type of exchanges please watch the [video](https://databricks.com/session_eu19/physical-plans-in-spark-sql) from David Vrba

Comment: This is the best solution if you are finding the max/min values on integer/double columns.
 If you need to find max in a Timestamp column, it is not the best solution. The joins on Timestamp can cause issues on a huge dataframes. 
 I personally experienced a split of data on such joins.
 So in this case I suggest to use Window.... Or at least cast to long a timestamps before to make join!

Answer (score 4):

There is another good solution for PySpark 2.0+ where `over` requires window argument:
*empty* `partitionBy` or `orderBy` clause.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

df.withColumn(f"{c}_min", F.min(f"{c}").over(W.partitionBy())
#  or
df.withColumn(f"{c}_min", F.min(f"{c}").over(W.orderBy())
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also able to specify without **`orderby,partitionBy`** clauses in window function
 **`min("<col_name>").over()`**

**`Example:`**

```
//sample data
val df=Seq((1,2,3),(4,5,6)).toDF("i","j","k")

val df1=df.columns.foldLeft(df)((df, c) => {
  df.withColumn(s"${c}_min",min(col(s"${c}")).over()).
  withColumn(s"${c}_max",max(col(s"${c}")).over()).
  withColumn(s"${c}_mean",mean(col(s"${c}")).over())
})

df1.show()
//+---+---+---+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+------+
//|  i|  j|  k|i_min|i_max|i_mean|j_min|j_max|j_mean|k_min|k_max|k_mean|
//+---+---+---+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+------+
//|  1|  2|  3|    1|    4|   2.5|    2|    5|   3.5|    3|    6|   4.5|
//|  4|  5|  6|    1|    4|   2.5|    2|    5|   3.5|    3|    6|   4.5|
//+---+---+---+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+------+
```

Comment: I got **over() missing 1 required positional argument: 'window'**. Seems like a Window is required ? I am using Pyspark

Comment: You can do something like that:
1) create a column that has the same value for the whole dataframe
   .withColumn("all", lit("1"))
2) Use this column for a window:
val window= Window.partitionBy("all")

Answer (score 0):

I know this was a while ago, but you could also add a dummy variable column that has the same value for each row. Then the partition contains the entire dataframe.

```
df_dummy = df.withColumn("dummy", col("index") * 0)
w = Window.partitionBy("dummy")
```